# Creating a stacked card appearance

Tags: android, layout, android-cardview, xml-drawable

Hey guys so I have this pretty simple card view and I am trying to create a sort of stacked look. The first card should be on top and each other card should appear behind it. I have tried placing a layout drawable on the card background to show blank cards but it does not appear. I have also tried changing the root to a frame layout and placing the background there. Any help is appreciated !.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/newspaper_card_background"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--suppress AndroidLintContentDescription -->
        <com.example.xyzreader.ui.DynamicHeightNetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/photo_placeholder"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/ltgray"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_subtitle"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/light_grey_text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_below="@+id/article_title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Any luck implementing this one ?